# Strange case of intellisense not working in Visual Studio 2015/2017

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-2017, intellisense

When a code block is auto-generated in Visual Studio as result of a suggestion...

[image]

...we are automatically prompted to type inside a little red box, like this:

[image]

But inside that red little box intellisense doesn't work! Is there a way to fix this? It's rather annoying.

Comment: Works just fine on my machine™.  Watch out for some kind of add-in screwing this up.

Comment: Does this issue only happens in this code block? Please run the command: devenv /safemode to check if the installed extension effect it or not.